# Wireguard queries showing up in PiHole, but no return packets are recieved by the client

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, docker, wireguard

I've got a docker bridge network with Wireguard and PiHole containers running within. I've forwarded all necessary ports, and using `192.168.1.208` (My server ip) as my DNS in the router works great on my WiFi/LAN.

In my Wireguard client (my Android phone for example), if I leave the wireguard DNS field empty or set it to `172.28.0.3` (The docker internal IP of PiHole), the VPN works beautifully and I can access all my other `192.168.1.208:xxxx` services running on my server. Except, none of my internet traffic runs through pihole, so I do not get the blocking I set up.

If I set `192.168.1.208` as my Wireguard client DNS, however, something stange happens. My traffic will indeed be routed though pihole, as I can see the wireguard `172.28.0.2` traffic in the pihole query logs. However, random websites and apps will fail to load. The pages that fail to load seem entirely random. Youtube and instagram works, but brave search does not. Most websites do not load, but google search works. Reddit does not. I can still however see all their traffic in the pihole query logs. For example, if I try to connect to reddit, I will see that pihole sees my reddit traffic on `172.28.0.2`, but on my phone it just loads forever.

Is this a return routing issue somehow? Since clearly the traffic is flowing through pihole but not returning to the phone? It does not make a difference if pihole is on `172.28.0.2` or `172.28.0.3`

Answer (score 0):

In your phone's WireGuard config, the `DNS` field controls what server your phone uses for DNS resolution, but the `AllowedIPs` field controls what traffic your phone actually routes through its WireGuard network.

It sounds like your phone's WireGuard config is probably something like the following (where `203.0.113.2` would be some Internet-accessible IP address that forwards port `51820` to your WireGuard container):

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.0.0.123
DNS = 192.168.1.208

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.0/24
Endpoint = 203.0.113.2:51820
```

This would mean that while your phone uses your Pi-hole to resolve its DNS queries (like to look up the IP address for YouTube or Reddit), it still uses its regular Internet connection to actually access those Internet sites (ie to connect to those IP addresses). The IP addresses returned by some of your Pi-hole DNS queries might not be accessible from your phone's Internet connection (like because they're specific to a CDN cache usable only by your Pi-hole's Internet connection).

If you changed the `AllowedIPs` setting on your phone to include all traffic like the following (`0.0.0.0/0` for IPv4 and `::/0` for IPv6), it would also send all your Internet traffic through your WireGuard container:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.0.0.123
DNS = 192.168.1.208

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = 203.0.113.2:51820
```

In your WireGuard container, you would also need to have some firewall rules set up to SNAT traffic to the Internet (eg something like `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`), but you may have something like that in place already for both the Internet and traffic to your LAN.

See the [Tunnel all Internet traffic](https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/vpn/wireguard/route-everything/) and [Make local devices accessible](https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/vpn/wireguard/internal/) sections of the Pi-hole documentation for more details.